# Initializing Vector of Structs in Constructor C++

Tags: c++

in Class.h

```
Struct Node
{
   int ID;
   int position;

}
```

In class Class.cpp I am initializing vector of structs which leads to core dump error

```
Class::Class(const branch& branches):mybranches(branches)
{
  for (const auto & branch:mybranches)
  {
    Node* node
    node->ID= branch->ID
    node->position= branch->position

    mynodesvector.push_back(std::move(node));

  }
}
```

However initializing it like this leads to no error

```
Class::Class(const branch& branches):mybranches(branches)
{
  for (const auto & branch:mybranches)
  {
    Node node
    node.ID= branch->ID
    node.position= branch->position

    mynodesvector.push_back(&node);

  }
}
```

I want to know what is the reason for the core dump error with initializing it as pointer to struct.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. What is `branch`? What is `Tree`? And what is `Struct` (with capical/upper-case `S`) or `size`? Also please try to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What @Someprogrammerdude said ... but also: you are not initialising node in the first example, it is *declared* as a pointer to a `Node` struct, but it is not init'd explicitly to point to a Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not create/allocate an object to which `node*` shall point; so dereferencing `node` leads to undefined behaviour;

```
Node* node;
node->ID= branch->ID;  // UB here...
```

However, allocating an object like

```
Node* node = new Node();
node->ID= branch->ID; 
...
```

should work.

In your second example, you define a `Node`-object (and not just a pointer to it). So at least accessing its members is save.

```
Node node;  // defines a Node-object.
node.ID= branch->ID; //save
node.position= branch->position; // save
```

Note, however, that you push_back a pointer to an object with block scope; when you dereference this pointer later, the actual object will be out of scope and you get undefined behaviour then.

```
mynodesvector.push_back(&node);
```

I'd suggest to have a look at `std::shared_ptr<Node>`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @Stefan Lechner:

The version which throws no direct error has a bug which is likely to blow up whenever you try to modify the values in the mynodesvector:
 you initialize a struct on the stack and then push its address into a vector. Once an iteration of the for loop has terminated, the Node instance is destructed, but you still have the pointer to it in the vector.

```cpp
for (const auto & branch:mybranches)
  {
    {
        Node node
        node.ID= branch->ID
        node.position= branch->position

        mynodesvector.push_back(&node);
    }
    // here, Node is dead, but the pointer to it lives on.
  }
```

In order to find bugs like that that escape your code control I recommend enabling compiler warnings and using appropriate [sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers).

Comment: @Hazem Abaza I think the answer of Stephan Lechner is more complete, he added my point, I think his answer should be accepted